# Save button does not work on Modal Dialog while adding a calendar item?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, internet-explorer

The save button (top and bottom) does not work on the add new calendar event modal dialog. 
[image]
Surprisingly it seems to work fine in chrome and firefox but not IE.

Once I remove my custom branding though it works ok.

Now, is this an Issue with my Browser or my Custom Branding. 
Has anyone else faced a similar issue?

Where do I even start to look for the problem??

Update: Script errors found on IE dev tools:
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Hi user7400, I had a similar issue to yours but I was opening a modal dialog across site collections, so my Save functionality was being prevented by the built-in XSS security in SharePoint.  The fact that removing your custom branding resolves the issue means it has to be something you have implemented.  If you take the XSS as an idea that may be the cause, it could be a script link or similar that's causing the issue.  You could try temporarily stripping out any Script Links or CSS references to see if that sorts it out.

Comment: Had an after thought that it may be that in your custom branding you are missing a script reference?  You could check by analyzing the downloaded files using Firebug and the IE Dev Toolbar.  That's a second idea that may be equally useless! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Per I did look up to see if I was missing terminations and yes I did. But once I fixed it, I continued to face the same issues. I am assuming it is a bug with IE9.

Well for now I have downgraded my browser to IE 8 and have no issues!:)

Comment: Here is a link indicating that this is actually a bug:  
http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2012/07/22/convert-sharepoint-2010-master-page-html5/#bugs

Answer (score 1):

Well... **its your custom branding.**

Both of these buttons rely on onclick events executing javascript so its likely something is causing a javascript error on the page.

It could be that this error is happening before the click actually happens (i.e. page/modal load) so don't just look at the javascript that happens after the click.

Use IE developer toolbar & script debugging to find out exactly where this is going wrong.

Comment: @Steve Here is an interesting update! I set the Browser's Document and Browser mode to IE8 and now everything seems to work just fine. I did however bring up IE dev tools (while running on IE9 mode) and I have put up a screenshot of the script errors I found on clicking the save button. There were no error prior to clicking it. Please note that I am running IE9.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that your custom branding is missing some termination. Could be >, ", ' or ) such that depending on the recovery model of the browser a script reference or function declaration is missed.